# How do you configure Podman to use IPv6 on Debian

Tags: debian, linux-networking, ipv6, docker-networking, podman

I am running rootless podman (podman version 4.3.1). I cannot get IPv6 working.

**Setup**

In `/etc/containers/containers.conf` I have set:

```
network_cmd_options = [
    "port_handler=slirp4netns",
    "enable_ipv6=true"
]

network_backend = "netavark"
```

Following this I have reset podman with `podman system reset`. I then defined a network with `podman netowrk create --ipv6 mytestnetwork`.

I now create a pod with `podman pod create --name mytestpod --publish 8080:80 --network mytestnetwork`. Finally, I create a nginx container in the `mytestpod` pod with `podman run --name test-web --pod mytestpod -d docker.io/library/nginx`. I have the following nginx.conf set up in the container:

```
server {
    listen  [::]:80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://[some:ipv6:address]:1234;
    }
}
```

**The problem**

I cannot connect to the Nginx container because it is listening on IPv6. If I add the line `listen 80` (for IPv4) then I can connect, but obviously the `proxy_pass` will not work as that is IPv6. I have ensured that nftables has no rules that are blocking connections. `ss -tlp` reports that `rootlessport` is listening on the Nginx port.

I realise that I could have all of my pods on the host network but I have a lot of containers and pods and I really want to use port mapping and have some network isolation. I have been stuck on this problem for over a week now and I've read and re-read the podman docs and Redhat blogs to no avail. Any help or suggestions appreciated!